# C++ "vector" with elements of variable size

Tags: c++, boost, data-structures, stl, containers

For a very specific application, I'd like to use a container with elements of variable size and contiguous in memory. The rationale is that access will be mostly sequential, so having all the data in the same linear data structure should help caching behavior.

Of course random access will be impossible, but the data structure should be dynamically-sized with a vector-style `push_back` method.

Does a container like this exist? How is it called?

Edit to address Arne Mertz' comment:

The structure I want to represent is a graph. The container would contain the list of nodes with for each node the list of edges, probably represented as a list of pointers to other (previous) nodes.

```
struct Node {
  //various fixed size fields about the node itself
  ...

  unsigned short n_edges;
  Node * edges[n_edges]; // schematically
};
```

Comment: @H2CO3 : I'd like the elements to be contiguous in memory. I've edited the question to make things clearer.

Comment: Then `std::vector`. If you want contiguous elements, then that's an array or vector with `O(1)` access and `O(n)` insertion and removal. If you want `O(1)` insertion and removal, then that's a link list and it then has `O(n)` traversal, and it is not contiguous in memory. You can't eat your lunch **and** have your lunch, decide which one you want.

Comment: Containers with variable elements are at best hard to implement. Also you would have difficulties to do anything with those elements, since you cannot know what type the N'th element of the container will have. One thing hat comes to mind ist `boost::variadic` or C++11's unions that support class type members. It will be difficult to implement anyways. If you tell us more about the types of your data, we can give you more details on possible implementations.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Well, maybe too long for a comment, OK.

Comment: You raise a very good point. I'll edit my question to give an example.

Comment: This is indeed not an answer.

Comment: Premature optimisation?

Comment: @PeterWood : what makes you think this optimization is premature? ;-)

Comment: @static_rtti Well, are you having caching problems?

Comment: @static_rtti glad to hear it (if you know what I mean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [Boost Intrusive singly linked list](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/intrusive/slist.html). You need to implement your own allocation yourself. You can simply allocate a large area (of type char[]) and create your objects inside this area with increasing addresses (don't forget alignment). If your area is full you can simply create a further one. But you have to do all allocation for your own and manage object lifetime. In addition you can use a `std::vector` as a supporting structure for O(1) access.

Comment: That would work, but the pointer to the next element would be wasted.

Comment: I think a list has its advantage for using with algorithms. For example you can iterate. There is http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/intrusive/function_hooks.html which explains how calculate these pointers.

Comment: Upon reflection, I think this is the best answer. In my example, the number of edges can be deduced from the pointer, so nothing is wasted.

Answer (score 2):

you could create a `std::vector<char> v` combined with a `std::list<size_t> l`. `v` will act as a growable char buffer and `l` will contain the offsets to your objects.

Now you need to write your own push_back which inserts the current offset into the std::list and copies the object at location: &v[offset] (remember to increase v beforehand).

```
template <class T>
void push_back(T t)
{
    size_t vectorSize = v.size());
    size_t objectSize = sizeof(T);

    l.pushback(vectorSize);

    v.reserve(vectorSize + objectSize);
    st::memcpy(&v[vectorSize], &t, objectSize);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of solving this is to use an internal void pointer. Then, each element is stored in that memory. Each element begins with its size. Iterating over the container would increment a byte pointer by the size of current element. If you want random access, you can use a directory containing pointers to all elements.

Comment: Yeah, that's about the idea. I was wondering if this sort of thing was already well-known, and perhaps already implemented as an obscure part of boost or even the standard library.

Comment: Checkout the source code of a Doom WAD editor. Doom WADs have object (or lump) sizes in the directory, but you do not want that because then you would have to make directory lookup for each item when you iterate, which can be significantly slower because of increased number of cahce misses.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a class with a chunk of dynamic memory.
Write a function to push a variable length structure on the end of the chunk.
put the offset of the chunk in a vector to give you easy iteration of the chunk,
and random access of the chunk.

When the dynamic memory area becomes full, reallocate it larger and copy the old chunks data into it.

Rinse Repeat.

Comment: Nope.  You have to dynamically allocate a chunk of memory for the variable length elements.   As you load that you store the pointer to the new element in the vector.

Comment: @EvilTeach : the vector would only add random access to my data structure. That's nice, but I'm asking about the way the "chunk of memory" is implemented.